# Hijacking onchange event without interfering with original function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onchange

I'm writing on a library I want to include on different pages who might already use the `onchange` event - is there any way to attach my event to `onchange` without removing the original one?

EDIT:

`onchange` on the window object not only a single element - `onchange` as in a hash change in the url etc. sorry if I confused them!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm correct it sounds like you want to inject new code into an existing event.  This may help you if you want a pure JavaScript solution and here is a fiddle demonstrating the feature. http://jsfiddle.net/VZCve/1/

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElementId");

element.onchange = (function (onchange) {
  return function(evt) {
    // reference to event to pass argument properly
    evt  = evt || event;

    // if an existing event already existed then execute it.
    if (onchange) {
      onchange(evt);
    }

    // new code "injection"
    alert("hello2");
  }
})(element.onchange);
```

**EDITED:**  Now that the tags are changed and you are reference jQuery in your Question

jQuery will continue to bind new functions using [jQuery.change().](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

note the following will execute all change functions assigned

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myElement").change(function() { alert('executed') });
  $("#myElement").change(function() { alert('executed again') });
  $("#myElement").change(function() { alert('executed again again') });
});
```

When you trigger the change event for the element in the selector you will receive 3 alerts.

Note the order of the events firing is dependent on the order each function was bound to the element.

Here is a simple fiddle demonstrating the functionality in jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/VZCve/

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery's `.change()` function to assign an `onchange` handler will not override existing `onchange` events (or other jQuery-assigned handlers). See a working demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/EyKdm/

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers have an `addEventListener` which can do it but
[dean.edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/) solution is better

is more compatible with older browsers

you could also use a costem eventhandeler(s) whitch call array's of functions (done properly you could handle the `return` value of the sub-functions to decide if you want to run the next function, also couts for `event`

```
if(typeof element.onclickfunctions == "undefined"){
  element.onclickfunctions = [];
}
element.onclickfunctions.push( function(event){return Myfunct(event);});//or var
element.onclick = function(event){
  for(x in element.onclickfuncitons){
    if(! x(event)){
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

code not tested please comment before downvote