# How to find what ASP.NET AJAX event handlers are associated with a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, asp.net-ajax

I'm customizing an existing ASP.NET 3.5 AJAX web application that I can't modify the source code to (it's SharePoint 2010).

I need to add a click event handler as the first event on a Close button. However, I'd like to check what the existing event handlers already registered on this button do first, so I don't mess anything up.

I'm still learning ASP.NET AJAX and can see the [Sys.UI.DomEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311047%28v=vs.90%29) has methods to add and remove event handlers, but not enumerate them. I know jQuery and am familiar with JavaScript debugging in Chrome.

How can I see **which events are registered** and **insert a custom event handler** at a particular position?

Comment: Are you able to inject your javascript below other scripts on the page, or are you restricted to a particular location within the html?

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique that will at least allow you to be the first in line (unless another script employs the same trick - unlikely).

What you have to do is hijack the click event.  This related question demonstrates the technique: [Hijacking onchange event without interfering with original function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744574/hijacking-onchange-event-without-interfering-with-original-function)

All we do is redefine the `click` function to be one of our own choosing, e.g.

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('button1')
var oldClick = myButton.click;

myButton.click = function(evt) {
  //do whatever you want.  When done, call the default click function:
  if (oldClick) oldClick(evt);
}
```

(the syntax in the linked question is superior, but the above code is easier to read).