# How to handle js popup dialogs in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to know in a chrome extension when a JS popup window, like an alert or confirm dialog, is opened.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there any chrome.* api or other api for this?
2. Are these kinds of dialogs a specific chrome.window object?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think theres anything for that.  But if your desperate you could add a content script to every page that hijacks window.alert with your function that sends a message to some other part of extension or reacts to it itself and then call the normal window.alert function.  Look up js function hijack on Google and you should get more info on the technique....this looks good... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744574/hijacking-onchange-event-without-interfering-with-original-function

Comment: but there is no way in chrome extension to auto click the new opened alert window,right? What about build a NPAPI plugin?

Comment: Have no idea on the NPAPI as I only do JS.  But on the auto click, if you hijack alert then you dont have to call the original alert you could just return true or whatever you want it to be.